# Xamarin Android Visual Studio layout not rendering when creating new blank app

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to create new project using xamarin android blank app. When I try to open the `main.axml` layout, it give below error:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaCommunicationContext.ReadMessageLoop() in C:\d\lanes\4699\1be4f0c9\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java\JavaCommunicationContext.cs:line 227
```

Comment: What is the version number of your Xamarin?

Comment: have you tried to use open it with Source Code (Text) Editor or with encoding?

Comment: xamarin version Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me when I open the layout. It supposed to be a version problem of xamarin (check this post :

[Unable to render xamarin android layout](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96994/unable-to-render-xamarin-android-layout)

I ckeck that version, it's the 4.5.0.476, the same as the post above.
I'll try to downgrade this version, I'll keep you informed

Comment: Did you manage to get xamarin work. I am already give up on xamarin and start using android studio

Comment: I gave up with xamarin android a long time ago, impossible to downgrade the version of xamarin to try to make it work, and no support on their forum. So I did like you, going on android studio ... I'm sorry.